# Crash with unrecognized selector in prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

The issue is with this line:

```
ExtraTeamInfoObject *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:row];
```

Please take a look at the code below,

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"teamDetailsSeg"]) {

        TeamDetailsTableViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        long row = [myIndexPath row];

        ExtraTeamInfoObject *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:row]; 
        // THIS IS THE PROBLEM

        detailViewController.teamDetailModel = item;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"StandingsIdent";

    StandingsViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    TeamObject *item = [tableData objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    long row = [indexPath row];

    if ([item isKindOfClass:[TeamObject class]]) {

        cell.cellTeamName.text = item.teamName;
        cell.cellTeamLogo.image = item.teamLogo;
        cell.cellPlayed.text = item.matchesPlayed;
        cell.cellWins.text = item.wins;
        cell.cellTies.text = item.ties;
        cell.cellLoses.text = item.loses;
        cell.cellPoints.text = item.points;
        cell.cellTeamPosition.text = _teamPosition[row];
        cell.cellInfo.text = _infoLeague[row];

    }
    else {}
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TeamObject teamFullNames]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10ac548b0'

Comment: Your `tableData` seems an array of `TeamObject`, why you assign its element to `ExtraTeamInfoObject *`.

Comment: that wouldn't matter, since TeamObject is used in maincontroller and the other in other view controller

Comment: It seems like this is another way of asking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716298/error-while-trying-to-go-to-another-view-controller-with-my-segue-method

Comment: The error is referring to [TeamObject teamFullNames]: where is that declared.? That is where the issue is. Search your code and find out where it is and remove that. Or add that in your cell index path so it can be selected if that is what you want.

Comment: this is declared in my main view, the issue is within that line I'm sure